# NestJs - Communication between two microservice by Docker

Tags: docker, microservices, nestjs, docker-image

**Problem**

I implemented a microservice application using **Nestjs** including an ***auth*** service and an ***api-gateway*** over `TCP` by docker service name as follows:

- api-gateway => **app.module.ts**

```js
import { Inject, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientProxy, ClientsModule, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { GoogleStrategy } from './auth/strategies/google.strategy';

@Module({
  
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name:'SERVICE_AUTH',
        transport:Transport.TCP,
        options:{
          host: 'auth',
          port: 9090
        }
      },
    ])
    ,UserModule, AuthModule],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AppService,GoogleStrategy],
  
})
export class AppModule {
  @Inject("SERVICE_AUTH") private readonly clientServiceA: ClientProxy
}
```

- auth-microservice => **main.ts**

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { Logger } from "@nestjs/common";

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(AppModule, {
    transport: Transport.TCP,
    options: {
      host: "api-gateway",
      port: 9090
    }
  });
  app.listen(() => Logger.log("Microservice Auth is listening"));
}
bootstrap();
```

I build their images separately based on docker file without using `docker-compose`. But when they run like the below image on the same network, the `api-gateway` cannot access to the `auth` service:

**Output Error**

```sh
[Nest] 1   - 06/21/2021, 8:26:05 AM   [ClientTCP] Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN auth +32740ms
My error:  Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN auth
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:69:26) {
  errno: -3001,
  code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'auth'
}
```

- Console error image when calling an method of **auth** microservice through **api-gateway**:

[image]

Any point can help me.

Thanks

Comment: What are the image files you've attached to the question?  Can you edit the question to include the actual source code necessary to reproduce the question (as text, not images) and any relevant error messages you get?

Comment: Hi. Yes of course. I've already updated that.

Comment: check the `host` in the configuration. is `api-gateway` and `auth` a valid host in your docker network? i would suggest you just try to use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. bind different services to a different port, ie: api-gateway = 9090, auth = 9091